# How to display single row after prepared select statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following Select statement prepared:

```
$category = "Acoustic Guitars"; //product id

//create a prepared statement
$query = "SELECT id, Category, Manufacturer, Model, Color, LargeImage1, AM_price, RRP, Featured FROM products WHERE Category = ?";
$statement = $GuitarDB->prepare($query);

   $statement->bind_param('s', $category);


$statement->execute()
    $statement->bind_result($id, $Category, $Manufacturer, $Model, $Color, $LargeImage1, $AM_price, $RRP, $Featured);
```

which displays the results fine when I do the following:

```
print '<table border="1">';

    //fetch records
    while($statement->fetch()) {
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
        print '<td>'.$Category.'</td>';
        print '<td>'. $Manufacturer.'</td>';
        print '<td>'.$Model.'</td>';
        print '</tr>';

    }   
    print '</table>';

    //close connection
    $statement->close();
```

However I just want to display 1 row how would I go about that because:`print $id` for example gives me `0`
This might be very easy but I am really struggling. Any help welcome.

Comment: You want to display first record of $statement array right?

Comment: yes that's right. however I want to be able to display the other found records at a later stage. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes you can prepare two array where first array will have first record and second array will have remaining records..and you can use easily both arrays in your application.

Comment: Giving limit to your mysql query is not solution for your query..you want remaining records also..how can you will get this..? another query? it will be overhead to php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease update your code to print only one row from an array.

```
print '<table border="1">';
        $row = null;
        //fetch records
        while($statement->fetch()) {

            if($row == null) {      
            print '<tr>';
            print '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
            print '<td>'.$Category.'</td>';
            print '<td>'. $Manufacturer.'</td>';
            print '<td>'.$Model.'</td>';
            print '</tr>';
            }
          $row++;
        }   
        print '</table>';

        //close connection
        $statement->close();
```

if You only want to show a single row then why you are fetching all the results from DB. PLease update your query as below.

```
$query = "SELECT id, Category, Manufacturer, Model, Color, LargeImage1, AM_price, RRP, Featured FROM products WHERE Category = ? limit 1";
```

Comment: That does it, is there a way to miss out the whole while loop and just print/echo out one row? echo $statement['id'] for example?

Answer (score 2):

Try this..You can use **break** to get out of while loop after printing first record..no need to use another variable..

```
print '<table border="1">';
while($statement->fetch()) {     
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$Category.'</td>';
    print '<td>'. $Manufacturer.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$Model.'</td>';
    print '</tr>';
    //you can use break to get out this while loop after printing first data
    break;
}   
print '</table>';

//close connection
$statement->close();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I voted up cause can't tick two correct answers, sorry.

Comment: @Ria its not matter of vote..matter of correct solution for your query..Thanks